# Populate object at runtime

Tags: autofixture

My problem is a bit of an odd one and I don't think it's really something Autofixture can solve but here goes;

We have a test that loops through every `ICloneable` in our assembly and attempts to clone it. Currently there is a horrific `Populate` method I want to get rid of and replace. It checks the type of each property and assigns a default value based on that (a nice, big, long if else statement).

The problem I have here is that I don't want to have to maintain a specific list of `Autofixture.Register` methods, as that is more maintenance than the method itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
private void CheckAssemblyClones(Assembly entitiesAssembly)
{
    foreach (Type entityType in entitiesAssembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICloneable))
                    && !t.IsAbstract
                    && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null))
    {
        ICloneable original = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType) as ICloneable;

        //Horrible method is used here to populate the object
        //This is where I tried to add fixture.Create(original) but it
        //doesn't like this original is an interface. If I use entityType
        //directly it complains as there are interfaces within the class
        //implementations that are later fulfilled using an IoC
        PopulateProperties(original, true);

        //Tried this, which fails because it is an ICloneable
        //var fixture = new Fixture();
        //original = fixture.Create(original);

        MethodInfo cloneMethod = entityType.GetMethod("Clone", new Type[]
        {
            typeof(Boolean)
        });
        object clone = cloneMethod.Invoke(original, new object[]
        {
            true
        });
    }
}

private static PropertyInfo[] PopulateProperties(object obj, bool nest)
{
    //var fixture = new Fixture();
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        //Tried this but it failed due to PropertyInfo being an abstract class.
        //var autoProp = fixture.Create(property);
        //For every type set a default value for the property
    }

    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Fixture.Create`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have updated the main post.

Comment: _How_ have you tried to use `Fixture.Create`? Where did you run into problems?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I have tried this. I've detailed what I have tried in the comments but I will outline it again here. The main issue is that the objects are boxed with no way of unboxing them at runtime as the types are not known. In the PopulateProperties method `fixture.Create` cannot be used on `PropertyInfo` as it is an abstract class. currently that method is a huge if-else which does `property.PropertyType == typeof(char){ property.SetValue(obj, 'a' }` etc etc for each known type.

Comment: Have you tried letting AutoFixture create `original`, instead of using `Activator.CreateInstance`?

Comment: It was the first thing I tried however as `original` is of type `ICloneable`, an interface, it is unable to do this as there is no implementation registered and I can't register an implementation as it isn't known at compile time. I then attempted to do it to each property within the object, as all I really need is the object to be given a value, but was presented with the error mentioned above.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated the code block to reflect what I've said in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to write a convention-based test that covers the behaviour of multiple types. That's what the [AutoFixture.Idioms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Idioms) is for.

Sketching out a possible implementation, you should look into defining a class that derives from `IdiomaticAssertion`:

```
public class CloneableAssertion : IdiomaticAssertion
{
    private readonly ISpecimenBuilder builder;

    public CloneableAssertion(ISpecimenBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("builder");

        this.builder = builder;
    }

    public override void Verify(Type type)
    {
        // Check if type is ICloneable before trying to create it.
        // Return if it's not ICloneable.

        // If this.builder is a standard Fixture object, the returned
        // object will be populated with data, if possible.
        var sut = (ICloneable)Create(type);

        // Insert test against sut here...
    }

    private object Create(Type type)
    {
        return new SpecimenContext(this.builder).Resolve(type);
    }
}
```

For more comprehensive examples, see the source code of AutoFixture.Idioms. The best place to start is probably [WritablePropertyAssertion](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/Idioms/WritablePropertyAssertion.cs), which is fairly small and simple.

---

Perhaps you're implementing `ICloneable` for internal use only, in which case it's fine, but you should, however, be aware that use of it is [discouraged in public APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable):

> we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs

Comment: Thanks for this, Mark, I'll look into implementing this today. As I've mentioned this is an legacy system that I'm trying to futilely clean up a little, it's not a public API.

Comment: What would I be using to fulfill the ISpecimineBuilder? Would I need one for each type I want it to build?

Comment: @Questioning You can use a `Fixture` instance. See the _Idioms_ project's [Scenario file](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/IdiomsUnitTest/Scenario.cs) for examples.